# How create multiple serialization?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

How create multiple serialization ? Now the system write just last record to `txt`. I want create simple DB that will contain customers info. And what you think, about this method of storing data in `txt`.  ?

```
private static void WriteCustomers(){
            System.out.println("|______Registration module______|");
            try {

                System.out.println("First name: ");
                String firstName = reader.readLine();

                System.out.println("Last name: ");
                String lastName = reader.readLine();

                .....

                CustomerManagement obj = new CustomerManagement();
            CustomerManagementD customerManagementD = new CustomerManagementD();
                customerManagementD.setFirstName(firstName);
                customerManagementD.setLastName(lastName);

                .....

            obj.serializeCustomers(customerManagementD);
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.getMessage();
            }
        }
    public void serializeCustomers(CustomerManagementD customerManagementD) {

            FileOutputStream fout = null;
            ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

            try {

                fout = new FileOutputStream("CustomerManagement.txt");
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
                oos.writeObject(customerManagementD);

                System.out.println("Done");

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();

            } finally {

                if (fout != null) {
                    try {
                        fout.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (oos != null) {
                    try {
                        oos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Last question, If I use serialization, I will be able to Edit and Remove stored  particular objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A `txt`-file is used for text-only. The `ObjectOutputStream` stores more than then fields: it stores the classname (and serialVersionUID if present). Try to use `.dat` what is a generic extension for databases or datas.
2. You call the method `serializeCustomers` where `Customers` is plural and let me think we can store multiple Customer, but the parameter does not allow to use multiple customers. Instead, I suggest, to store a Set (like a `LinkedHashSet`) to store multiple customers, and yes, you can read and write to the `LinkedHashSet`.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

```
    private static void WriteCustomers(List<CustomerManagementD> list){

                    try {

                        System.out.println("First name: ");
                        String firstName = reader.readLine();

                        System.out.println("Last name: ");
                        String lastName = reader.readLine();

                        .....

                        // serialize collection of customers


                            customerManagementDArraysList.add(new CustomerManagementD(
                                    customerID,firstName,lastName,email,contactNo));
                            ObjectOutputStream outStream = null;
                            try {
                                outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                                for (CustomerManagementD p : list) {
                                    outStream.writeObject(p);
                                }

                            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                                System.err.println("Error opening file.");
                            } finally {
                                try {
                                    if (outStream != null)
                                        outStream.close();
                                } catch (IOException ioException) {
                                    System.err.println("Error closing file.");
                                }
                            }
                        }else if (finalcheck.equals("2")){
                            Adminswitch();
                        }
                        System.out.println("|______Customer was successfully saved______|\n   Press 'Enter' to continue...");
                        String absentinput = reader.readLine();
                            Adminswitch();

                    }catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

         private static ArrayList ViewCustomer(){
                try{
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                    ObjectInputStream oos =new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                    ArrayList<CustomerManagementD> customerManagementDArraysList = new ArrayList<>();
                    try {
                        while (true) {
                            CustomerManagementD cmd = (CustomerManagementD) oos.readObject();
                            customerManagementDArraysList.add(cmd);
                        }
                    }catch (EOFException e){
                     e.getMessage();
                    }
                     {
                         while (file.canRead()){
                             for (CustomerManagementD cmd : customerManagementDArraysList) {
                                 System.out.println("Customer ID: " + cmd.getCustomerID() + 
" First Name: " + cmd.getFirstName() +
     " Last Name: " + cmd.getLastName()+....);

                             }
                             break;
                        }
                    }
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();}

                return null;
            }
```